# Unbounded resolutions for Grothendieck abelian categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Consider the following result:

> **Theorem 1:** Let $\mathsf{A}$ be a Grothendieck abelian category. Then every complex in $\mathsf{C}(\mathsf{A})$ has a $K$-injective resolution.

As far as I know, the first proof of this result was in [Localization in categories of complexes and unbounded resolutions](http://webspersoais.usc.es/export9/sites/persoais/persoais/leo.alonso/papeles/locores4c.pdf). In 2003 another proof was published in [Resolution of unbounded complexes in Grothendieck categories](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82367908.pdf). There also seems to be a proof in Categories and Sheaves by M. Kashiwara and P. Shapira, but it also relies on some set theory and is quite long. I found no other proofs.

The second proof is possibly the shortest but, due to a lot of set theory involved, seems very strange to me. A more conceptual route seems to be using the Gabriel-Popescu theorem and Brown representability to prove corollary 5.2 in [Localization in categories of complexes and unbounded resolutions](http://webspersoais.usc.es/export9/sites/persoais/persoais/leo.alonso/papeles/locores4c.pdf) and then conclude the proof. That's better, but it is still quite long and difficult.

**Given the importance of Theorem 1, I wonder if there exist other, perhaps simpler, proofs of this result.**

Comment: @LeoAlonso I'm sorry I confused the dates. It's fixed now.

Comment: The set theory involved is the following observation: "a successor cardinal is regular", meaning that it bounds its cofinality. This is well explained in Lévy's book Basic set theory (at the beginning). It is already used to prove the existence of injectives in Grothendieck categories, and is the backbone of "small object arguments". It may not be a bad thing to invest in understanding it.

Comment: @LeoAlonso That's good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

It appears that this result may go back to a 1984 letter of Joyal to Grothendieck.  The reference to this letter, as well as some other early references, can be found in Example 3.2 in the paper [Cotorsion pairs, model category structures, and representation theory](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-002-0431-9).  Later references using this approach (based on the small object argument) include Corollary 7.1 in the 2007 paper [Kaplansky classes and derived categories](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-007-0148-x).  There is also a very recent paper of mine [Derived, coderived, and contraderived categories of locally presentable abelian categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.10797), Corollary 8.5.

Comment: How would you say your approach and the approach cited (are they the same?) compare to the ones I've cited? Would you mind explaining a little their relations?

Comment: A typed pdf version of Joyal's letter is available here: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~georges.maltsiniotis/ps/lettreJoyal.pdf Joyal states the theorem that the injective model structure exists on the category of unbounded chain complexes of a Grothendieck abelian category, which implies the existence of K-injectives through fibrant replacement. Joyal does not give a full proof: he gives a proof the analogue result for simplicial objects in a Grothendieck topos, and argue that the abelian situation is similar (which is true).